# Root can not create new files under /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.1

Tags: root, kvm, qemu

Basically, I try to fix vender reset bug for amd GPU passthrough
So I create a hook file for qemu and manually reset the GPU and HDMI devices:

```
    echo 'device_specific' > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/reset_method
    echo 'device_specific' > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.1/reset_method
```

Weird thing is the second echo didn't work. Then I find out sudo/root has no privilege under /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.1/ to create new file.

ls -al show:

```
lrwxrwxrwx root root 0 B Sun Feb  5 22:31:46 2023  0000:03:00.0 ⇒ ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0
lrwxrwxrwx root root 0 B Sun Feb  5 22:31:46 2023  0000:03:00.1 ⇒ ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.1
```

It shows root has rwx privilege for the folder, but why can I create files in it?

Comment: Files under `/sys` are generally virtual files maintained by the kernel. They're not regular linux files and you can't create new files in these directories. You can find some links to relevant documentation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs). You can often control devices by writing certain values to *existing* files.

Comment: @larsks Which means only 0000:03:00.0 supports reset_method. File `reset_method` already exists before I echo staff in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Symbolic links (indicated by the `l` in the first column in your listing) do not have real permissions, so the permissions there are meaningless.   Either look at the real file, or use the `-L` option of `ls` to get the real permissions.
- The /sys filesystem is a virtual filesystem with no storage backing it.  It is generated on the fly by the kernel and device drivers in the kernel.  If a file is missing, either the hardware that backs it doesn't exist or the driver doesn't support the feature the file represents.  You need to upgrade the kernel or load a driver or add hardware to fix that.
- Since /sys is virtual, even when you look at the real permissions on the file, they still don't have a lot of meaning, as the virtual filesystem doesn't have to honor them.
- Many files in /sys and /proc will ignore writes if you try to write data in the wrong format or try to write illegal values.  Remember, this data isn't saved per se, it is sent to a driver or the kernel which might change its internal settings, and might republish the actual resulting settings in the same or a different format.

Checking some random devices in my own system's `/sys/bus/pci/devices/*/` some have reset_method and some don't.

Looking in /usr/share/doc/linux-doc/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci.gz and searching for reset_method finds one entry which indicates that only some devices support this, and reading the file will give a list of methods.  The correct data to write to the file includes things in this list, the empty string, and "default".

Comment: I guess pci 0000:03:00.1 doesn't support reset. But qemu keep popping warning/error: `2023-02-06T18:33:34.230398Z qemu-system-x86_64: vfio: Cannot reset device 0000:03:00.1, no available reset mechanism.`